# I just dual booted 12.10 into my asus g74sx installed nvidia drivers and now I cant see the dash and pretty much anything HELP!

Tags: drivers, nvidia, resolution, screen

I installed some nvidia drivers on my laptop and now I cant see anything. Not the menu bar, the dash, no window buttons, that is to say the x the minimize button or the maximize one.

This is getting kinda annoying! How can I fix it? :(

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me. I think it installs the 304 drivers, and they seem to have a few problems on some systems with some of the cards.  Uninstall the nvidia-current drivers: Open a terminal window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> then type the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current
```

This will cause it to revert to the Nouveau driver module.  If you want to try an alternative Nvidia driver:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```

which worked very well for me.  If it doesn't for you remove that one as well:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current-updates
```

If you have trouble opening a terminal window above, try switching to a console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>